Examples of The Gelfand Representation Not Behaving
Currently I am trying to think of examples of Banach algebras $A$ where the Gelfand Map $\Gamma: A \longrightarrow C_0(\Omega(A))$ fails to be an isomorphism.  So far, I have come up with some mundane examples of where $\Gamma$ fails to be:

Onto
Injective
Isometric
Injective but not onto
is $0$
Is the identity map
is onto but not injective

For $1,4$ I took $A = \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ with the usual convolution product, and shows that although $\Gamma$ is injective by uniqueness of Fourier coefficients, it's image (the Fourier algebra) is not all of $C(\mathbb{T})$.
For $2,3,5$ I took $A$ to be the set of all nonconstant polynomials of degree at most $n$ with the convention that $x^p = 0$ for $p>n$ with the usual pointwise operations and norm $\lVert \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k x^k \lVert = \sum_{k=0}^n |\alpha_k|$.  Then the character space is empty, so $\Gamma: A \longrightarrow C(\emptyset) = \{0\}$ (I think this works?).
For $6$ I just took $A = C(X)$ for $X$ compact Hausdorff.
For $7$ I took the example for $2,3,5$ but added a unit $1$ (so there are constant polynomials and polynomials with constant term) , so there is exactly one character $\varphi$ , determined by it's evaluation at $1$ so that $\Gamma: A \longrightarrow C(\{\varphi\}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ where $\Gamma(f) = f_0$ where $\varphi(f)=f_0$.  Then $\Gamma(x) = 0$ since it's nilpotent as above but $\Gamma$ is still onto $\mathbb{C}$ ofcourse.
$\textbf{My Question Is Here}$:

Is my example for $2,3,5$ appropriate or correct?  The only thing I could think to make $\Gamma$ be $0$ is to force the character space to be empty, which at some level makes sense to me as $\ker(\Gamma)$ is otherwise an intersection of maximal ideals (atleast when the algebra is unital) so I need there to be no such ideals to intersect lol.

I'm stuck on finding examples of Banach algebras where $\Gamma$ is neither injective nor onto, but is nonzero, and where $\Gamma$ is injective, but not isometric.  Does anyone have any good (relatively elementary) examples of these two things happening?



I guess for a non-unital Banach algebra $A$, you defined a character to be a nonzero $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb C$? If that's the case, your example holds (and surely by definition, for the Gelfand transform to be $0$, the spectrum has to be empty), but the problem is what $C(\emptyset)$ is? It's resaonable to suggest it's $0$. Anyway, this is not so important.
You mean you want 6 and 7 to hold, not to fail?
Your $\mathcal l^1(\mathbb Z)$ is already injective but not isometric.
As for neither injective nor onto: Just combine the two ideas you already have. Let $A=\mathcal l^1(\mathbb Z)$ with convolution as multiplication and $\mathcal l^1$-norm. Let $B=A[x]/(x^2)=A\oplus Ax$ with norm $\|(a,b)\|=\|a\|+\|b\|$. Since $x$ is nilpotent, $x\mapsto 0$ for all characters, hence the Gelfand transform cannot be injective, also the spectrum of $B$ is the same as $A$, hence not surjective.

Yes for 6 and 7 to hold, my bad!  Thanks!  For $B$, do you mean that $A[x]$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients from $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$?

@Isochron yes, but also with the extra condition that $x^2=0$.
